# Find elements in a collection where an element has a field which is a list and a given value must belong to the list

Tags: spring, mongodb, criteria, mongotemplate

I would like to query the objects in my collection such as a given value must belong to the values in the stringArray

stringArray is the name of the field for each Obejct that contains a list of Strings

the strucutre of my collection in mongodb is

```
Object1
{
  field1
  field2
  stringArray[2] 
        0     String0
        1     String1
}

Object2
{
  field1
  field2
  stringArray[3] 
        0     String0
        1     String1
        2     String2
}
```

}

My query is:

```
     Query query = new Query();
     query.addCriteria(
            Criteria.where(theValueIamlookingFor).in("stringArray")                
     );               
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, myObject.class);
```

So far, it hasn't worked.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Think you have just flipped there order. Please try:

`Criteria.where("stringArray").in(theValueIamlookingFor)`

instead of the above

Comment: Thanks a lot !It works ! But I am a bit puzzled by the syntax, I thought that the syntax was: where (the element). in (the array) while in relaity it is where(the array) in (the element)

Comment: Indeed, the syntax is a bit counter-intuitive, but it's the key first, followed by a list of possible values. One would have expected to find the apples **in** the basket and not vice versa